# Laravel restful route ajax method post 405 method not allowed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I want to submit form using ajax with Laravel. But Ajax post method gives 405 method now allowed. I am using restful route.
My code is given below: 
My route file is given below:

```
Route::resource("a","AController");
```

My js file is given below:

```
var host = "http://example.com/";
var url = host + "a/store";
$('#form_id').on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url:url,
    data: data,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 1000,
    error:function() { alert("Error Submitting Information") }
  }).done(function(resp){

  });
});
```

My controller file :

```
public function store(Request $request){
  $input = $request->all();
}
```

But it gives 405 method not allowed error

Comment: Share your `web.php` code please. Have you registered the Route as a `post` one?

Comment: Are you sure the endpoint supports a POST request, and not a GET/PUT/DELETE?

Comment: I have updated my question with routes/web.php file @manniL

Comment: Do you have more custom routes for `a` implemented like `a/{somethinghere}`? In this case, please include the lines too here :)

Comment: No, I didn't had any custom route with a. My web.php file has only one route with a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `/store` part:

```
var host = "http://example.com/";
var url = host + "a/"; //<----
$('#form_id').on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url:url,
    data: data,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 1000,
    error:function() { alert("Error Submitting Information") }
  }).done(function(resp){

  });
});
```

By default, laravel will direct any POST request to `store` function in `AController`

Take a look on routes table in Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers